# ExpressJS: Sequelize method update need to show updated data as result not num of row updated

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I've API using ExpressJS and ORM Sequelize. I'm trying to do update using method `update()` from Sequelize. By default, it method will return number of row updated. But I want the result is the new data that just updated to show as response.

Here is my code:

```
update: async function (req, res, next) {
    var current_address_id = req.body.current_address_id,
        address = req.body.address

    PersonalInfo.findOne({
        where: {
            id: req.params.id
        }
    }).then(personal => {
        Address.create(
            {
                address: address,
            }
        ).then( resAddress => {
            PersonalInfo.update(
                {
                    current_address_id: resAddress.dataValues.id
                },
                {
                    where: {
                        id: req.params.id
                    }
                }
            ).then(resultUpdate => {
                console.log(resultUpdate);
                responseUtil.success(res, resultUpdate);
            }).catch(err => {
                responseUtil.fail(res, err);
            })
        })
    })
}
```

When I do `console.log(resultUpdate);` It give me `[1]` as the num of row  updated. What I need is the data of PersonalInfo that just updated.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting the documentation for what returns from the `update` operation for Sequelize, it returns the following:

> an array with one or two elements. The first element is always the
>   number of affected rows, while the second element is the actual
>   affected rows (only supported in postgres with options.returning
>   true.)

So, as you can see from your code, your update is returning an array with the number of affected rows, which is what the documentation says it will do. You can't change what the library itself will return.

You do have access to the values you are updating earlier on in your function, and if you really want, you could do a find on the record you are updating, which will return your model: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findOne

Comment: I'm sorry late to tell, I'm using sequelize and MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add `returning: true` at your query. Your code would be like

```
update: async function (req, res, next) {
var current_address_id = req.body.current_address_id,
    address = req.body.address

PersonalInfo.findOne({
    where: {
        id: req.params.id
    }
}).then(personal => {
    Address.create(
        {
            address: address,
        }
    ).then( resAddress => {
        PersonalInfo.update(
            {
                current_address_id: resAddress.dataValues.id
            },
            {
                where: {
                    id: req.params.id
                },
                returning: true
            }
        ).then(resultUpdate => {
            console.log(resultUpdate);
            responseUtil.success(res, resultUpdate);
        }).catch(err => {
            responseUtil.fail(res, err);
        })
    })
})
}
```